# NAT, Debian, iptables

Tags: debian, iptables, nat

I'm not sure how to phrase this exactly, which is why I'm posting a question because maybe that will help me to phrase the question properly, but basically I have a machine (machine c) visible to machine b through a private network. Machine c has no connection to any other network, but machine b does. Machine b has a connection to machine a and machine c. How would I go about exposing the connection from machine c to the outside world (machine a), if I only have access to machine b? Basically, I started at machine a, and I have full access to machine b, but my networking understanding is too amateur to figure out if I need iptables or something else to do what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`A <==> B <==> C`

With the vague information you provided, it seems like you would forward traffic via the interface which connects C to B and then to A.  There are various tools you can use for this, `iptables` is certainly one and `ip route` is another which I've used for some quick tests.  [Here's](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-configuring-default-route-with-ipcommand/) a link about `ip route` that should give you enough examples to get your self into a better situation.

Another way would be to use a SSH tunnel from C to A if you're trying to connect to something specific.  So you could do something like the following on C:

```
ssh -L localhost:9000:machineA:9000 user@machineB
```

## Links

- [Linux Set Up Routing with ip Command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-configuring-default-route-with-ipcommand/)
- [SSH Tunnel Example](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html)

Comment: I don't think I can use ssh, because I don't actually have access to c, just a and b, but I'm looking into the other stuff, thanks!